# Table Value in Moonsharp returning as null

Tags: c#, lua, moonsharp

I just started using Moonsharp in c# and was trying to test some things such as retrieving a value from a table. However, the compiler is telling me that the value t is null. What is the correct way to retrieve the number value from test?

script.lua:

```
test = {
 number = 3
}
```

c# code snippet:

```
        Script s = new Script();
        s.LoadFile("res/script.lua");
        Table t = s.Globals["test"] as Table;
        DynValue n = t.Get("number");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Above `Table t = s.Globals["test"] as Table;` put this line `var bob = s.Globals["test"];` Then execute past that line and let us know what the value of `bob` is.

Comment: @mjwills I did it. bob is null

Comment: Does `LoadFile` execute the code or just load it?

Comment: @mjwills I changed it to DoFile and it worked thanks!